# Двухмерный массив заполняется не правильно

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

Задача: поместить элементы массива matrix, которые больше нуля, по указанным "координатам".

```
const piece = {
  matrix: [
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]
  ],
  pos: { x: 3, y: 18 },
};

const playfield = new Array(20)
      .fill(new Array(10)
        .fill(0));

function lockPiece() {
    const {pos, matrix} = piece;

    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {
        if (matrix[y][x]) {
          playfield[pos.y + y][pos.x + x] = matrix[y][x];
          console.log(
            `playfield[${pos.y + y}][${pos.x + x}] = matrix[${y}][${x}]`
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

lockPiece();
```

В логе выводит

```
playfield[18][4] = matrix[0][1]
playfield[19][3] = matrix[1][0]
playfield[19][4] = matrix[1][1]
playfield[19][5] = matrix[1][2]
```

То есть, вроде бы всё правильно. Но на деле, итераций будто больше, поскольку *playfield* выглядит так:

```
0: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
15: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
length: 20
```

Но должен выглядеть так:

```
0: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
15: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19: (10) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
length: 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заполняется все правильно, а вот структура данных - не правильная:

Каждая строка матрицы у Вас ссылается на один и тот же массив, который Вы передали в `Array()`, т.е. `new Array(10).fill(0)`, чтобы это избежать можно сделать как-то  так

```
const playfield = new Array(20)
      .fill(0).map(() => new Array(10).fill(0));
```

```js
const piece = {
  matrix: [
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]
  ],
  pos: { x: 3, y: 18 },
};

const playfield = new Array(20)
      .fill(0).map(() => new Array(10)
        .fill(0));

function lockPiece() {
    const {pos, matrix} = piece;

    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {
        if (matrix[y][x]) {
          playfield[pos.y + y][pos.x + x] = matrix[y][x];
          console.log(
            `playfield[${pos.y + y}][${pos.x + x}] = matrix[${y}][${x}]`
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

lockPiece();
console.log(playfield.map(e=>JSON.stringify(e)))
```